# VirtualBox - Use DVD RW Drive in Windows Guest (POPOS Host)

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, virtualbox, dvd

In VirtualBox 6.1, how to I make my DVD RW Drive usable from a Windows 10 Guest? It is hosted in POPOS 21.04.  I thought this just worked when you installed the Guest Additions but apparently not.  If I run this on my Host:

```
sudo dmesg | egrep -i --color 'cdrom|dvd|cd/rw|writer'
[    1.236529] sr 3:0:0:0: [sr0] scsi3-mmc drive: 40x/40x writer dvd-ram cd/rw xa/form2 cdda tray
[    1.236535] cdrom: Uniform CD-ROM driver Revision: 3.20
```

So I was thinking it's a SCSI interface, so I added this under storage.

[image]

But when I attempt to access the "D" drive in Windows I get an error "Please insert disc"

Comment: The drive you're trying to access isn't your optical drive. It's a virtual one provided by Virtualbox and can be used with ISO files. You cannot access you real optical drive directly. You may try using shared folders.

Comment: You might also see if pass through is available. When I plug in a DVD, a notification asks me guest or host. I would look there. (I use VMware).

Comment: @John I think that's what "Live CD/DVD" is supposed to do. Maybe I don't have the controller or port right?

Comment: No, it isn't and I already explained that. Again, you may use the passtrough feature for any USB device easily (that's what @John meant by saying *when I plug in a DVD...*). Internal drives (SATA/PATA) can't be used in the same way with Virtualbox.